# how to send mail from phpmailer using SMTP Gmail settings

Tags: php, forms, smtp, gmail, phpmailer

I've created a contact form using PHP and am using PHPmailer class for sending mail using SMTP gmail settings. The form is working fine for other mail ids, but when I tried to change the settings to send mail via SMTP gmail, am getting error message as "SMTP Error: Could not connect to SMTP host. and SMTP -> ERROR: Failed to connect to server: Connection refused (111)".. Below is the code am using...

```
require 'PHPMailer/class.phpmailer.php';
 $mail = new PHPMailer();
$mail->IsSMTP();
$mail->Host = 'smtp.gmail.com';
$mail->Port = 587;
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;
$mail->Username = 'venkateshm2280@gmail.com';
$mail->Password = 'mmuxhssfdrqnsowp'; // Use the App Password you generated
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';
$mail->From = $_POST['email'];
$mail->FromName = $_POST['name'];
$mail->AddAddress('venkateshm2280@gmail.com', 'HR');
$mail->WordWrap = 50;
$mail->IsHTML(true);
$mail->AddAttachment($path);
$mail->Subject = 'Application for Programmer Registration';
$mail->Body = $message;
$mail->SMTPDebug = 2;
```

Is there any mismatch in the settings to send mail using SMTP Gmail.

Comment: https://mailtrap.io/blog/phpmailer-gmail/

Comment: Yes..I have created an App password and added the same in the place of password...but stiill am facing the problem....anyone plz help me to solve this issue...

Comment: https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting#smtp-error-could-not-connect-to-smtp-host

Comment: Thanks...CBroe...Yes...am using Godaddy server and trying to send mail using Gmail SMTP...according to the link provided, godaddy will sending emails through their own servers...so if we used only - $mail->Host = 'localhost'; we can send mail....am I right?

Comment: If you're on GoDaddy, they block outbound SMTP, and you have to use their `secureserver.net` mail server (which can also be accessed via `localhost`). This also means that it's impossible to send from a gmail address because google isn't about to put GoDaddy in their SPF. The best solution is to not use GoDaddy.

Comment: This is a networking question, not a programming question.

Answer (score 0):

@venkat I can't post comments, that is why I'm posting this as answer. Is your code working in local? If it is working, then as you mentioned please contact the go-daddy customer support. I have faced the similar kind of issue one of projects. They enable some setting and the mail started working.

> For TLS encryption the port number is 587, For SSl encryption the port number is 465

For better understanding please check the link https://kinsta.com/blog/gmail-smtp-server/

I'm using the below code, it is working for me.

```
require("./PHPMailer-master/src/PHPMailer.php");
require("./PHPMailer-master/src/SMTP.php");
$mail = new PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer();
$mail->IsSMTP(); // enable SMTP
$mail->SMTPDebug = 0; // debugging: 1 = errors and messages, 2 = messages only
$mail->SMTPAuth = true; // authentication enabled
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls'; // secure transfer enabled REQUIRED for Gmail
$mail->Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
$mail->Port = 587; // or 587
$mail->IsHTML(true);
$mail->Username = "venkateshm2280@gmail.com";
$mail->Password = "mmuxhssfdrqnsowp";
$mail->SetFrom("venkateshm2280@gmail.com");
$mail->Subject = "Application for Programmer Registration";
$mail->Body = $message;
$mail->AddAddress("venkateshm2280@gmail.com", "HR");
$mail->AddAttachment( $path , 'filename' );


$headers = "From: Sender\n";
$headers .= 'Content-Type:text/calendar; Content-Disposition: inline; charset=utf-8;\r\n';
$headers .= "Content-Type: text/plain;charset=\"utf-8\"\r\n"; #EDIT: TYPO

if (!$mail->Send()) {
    echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
} else {
    echo "Message has been sent";
}
```

Comment: Thanks @sayan0020...yes my code is working for other email ids (my official mail id) except gmail id it is not working..

Comment: From this link I've downloaded the phpmailer library https://github.com/Synchro/PHPMailer

Comment: Thanks for the code...am getting error as 2023-06-16 07:34:41 SMTP ERROR: Failed to connect to server: Connection refused (111)"... My files are in godaddy server and am trying to submit form from my server..

Comment: Try to connect with godaddy customer support, state the issue, I'm pretty sure there are some configuration on the server which might has to be enabled

Answer (score -2):

Try with below code.

```
require_once 'PHPMailer/class-phpmailer.php';
$mail = new PHPMailer();

$options["ssl"] = array(
    "verify_peer" => false,
    "verify_peer_name" => false,
    "allow_self_signed" => true,
);
$mail->SMTPDebug = false;
$mail->isSMTP();
$mail->Host = 'tls://smtp.gmail.com'; // This line was missing.
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;
$mail->Username = 'venkateshm2280@gmail.com';
$mail->Password = 'mmuxhssfdrqnsowp';
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';
$mail->Port = '587';
$mail->smtpConnect($options); // try with this line.
$mail->setFrom($_POST['email'], $_POST['name']);
$mail->AddAddress('venkateshm2280@gmail.com');
$mail->isHTML(true);
$mail->Subject = 'Application for Programmer Registration';
$mail->Body = $message;
if (!$mail->send()) {
    $finalResponse = 'Message could not be sent. Mailer Error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
} else {
    $finalResponse = 'success';
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the code..If I used $options["ssl"] .... am getting message as "this page is not working"

Comment: There are so many problems with this script I don't really know where to start.

Comment: Then try to use without $options["ssl"]. I am already using it in my wordpress project.